# How to disable smooth/fluid scrolling in office 2013 (Excel/Word)?

Tags: microsoft-office-2013

Today I've upgraded to Office 2013 (from 2010). First thing I noticed is that both Excel and Word (haven't tried other apps) use smooth/fluid scrolling when using the mouse scroll wheel. I haven't been able to find a way to disable this behavior. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 29):

Here you go:

Control panel > System and security > System > Advanced system settings (in upper-left side) > *Advanced* tab > *Settings* in Performance box > Visual effects:

Here please disable *Animate controls and elements inside windows.*

Comment: Thanks. Apparently smooth scrolling is very... "Advanced"...  ;-p

Comment: Unfortunately, in corporate environments with limited user rights, the Advanced System Settings is inaccessible.  We are stuck with the Microsoft defaults.  :(

Comment: This works in Windows 10 too (although it's located in `System / Ease of Access / Other options`)

Comment: As of 2019-18-12, in Windows 10 Pro (version 1903), it can be found at `Control Panel / Ease of Access Center / Make the computer easier to see / Turn off all unnecessary animations (when possible)` or at `Settings / Ease of Access / Display / Show animations in Windows`

Comment: This is very crazy.  Why did M$ want to (a) bury such a simple setting deep down in the navigation structure (b) prevent such a harmless setting from being changed by end users?  It's especially annoying if one just wants to disable it temporarily.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a trick to get the best possible performance:

1. With animations enabled, scrolling, typing and selecting text feels smooth, but lags badly.
2. With animations disabled, these feel somewhat rough, jerky and unpleasant, but the lag is gone.
3. There is also a workaround to have the best of both:
   **Enable animations, then start Word 2013, then disable animations**. This results is a very smooth and pleasant scrolling, typing and selection of text, with no lag. Newly opened Word documents will also work very smoothly. The only con is that every time you restart the application the workaround must be re-applied.

Here are two ways to disable animations:

- **Animate controls and elements inside windows**:
  This method takes effect immediately and can be used in step 3; all programs are affected.
- **Registry hack**: Affects only office applications. Takes effect after restarting the office application; not suitable for step 3.

  ```
  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Graphics]
  "DisableAnimations"=dword:00000001

  [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Graphics]
  "DisableAnimations"=dword:00000001
  ```

The behaviour on Word 2016 is the same, except that the overall performance is much degraded in all cases. Word 2010 ignores the animation settings. The experience is very smooth, and without any lag as in step 3.

If I find a way to load my DLL in Word at startup, I can make a tool to automate step 3. Any ideas on that?